# Number of integral solutions for the equation $x + 2y = 2xy$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How many  integral solutions does the following equation have? $$x + 2y = 2xy$$

I have tried hit and trail method and I got only one solution, namley, $x=y=0$.. But Is there any other way to solve this ? If so, tell me at very basic level and also tell how to solve such questions.

Comment: Please don't write in all caps. It doesn't help readability in any way, and makes it look like you are yelling at us.

Comment: Sorry. But could  u please  answer  fast i am in need fast. I am not argue ing with yu anyway . I am sorry. It was my 1 st question on this site

Comment: This site doesn't work fast. Well, it does some times. But it's not something you can expect it to. There are [250 000 unanswered questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) on this site. We answer the ones we feel like answering. Yelling doesn't help. Being in a hurry doesn't help. You might get an answer, or you might not. That's just how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea of @Doug M, you can actually write:

$$2y = \frac{x}{x-1} = 1+\frac{1}{x-1}$$

If $y$ is an integer, then $2y$ must be too, and $\frac{1}{x-1}$ as well. So $x-1 = \pm 1$ which leads to $x=2$ or $x=0$.

If $x=0$, $y=0$.

If $x=2$, $y=1$.

Those are the only solutions you can have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:

$x = y(2x -2)\\
y = \frac {x}{2(x-1)}$

With a little bit of thought you should be able to find an upper and lower bound of  $x.$